# How to make an app that adjusts to all screen sizes

Tags: css, html, windows-phone

I am new to Windows Phone development. Maybe this is a silly question.

I want to develop a WP 8.1 app using HTML, CSS and WinJS. As you know, Windows Phone has many sizes (4.5 inch, 4.7 inch, 5.5 inch, etc.). My app looks good on 4.5 inch screens, but it leaves some blank space on a 5.5 inch screen.

So my question is, how can my app fit all sizes of screen? I could define CSS for each size of screen as a solution, but is there another simpler way?

Comment: What have you tries so far? Any source code available?

Comment: I set all sizes in rem units rather than px, but seems still not working well

Comment: I also tried media queries in css, it works. But in this way I have to define css for all kinds of phone sizes. I just wonder is there a simple way.